# find venue with twitter id via API

Tags: foursquare

We integrate our service to 4sqr, this is done by our customer informing us of their venue-id from the 4sqr URL.  However, if a venue is claimed and a twitter associated with the venue the url is switched to one with the twitter id.

so, one of two things after this twitter acct is in place for a venue:
1. how does one find the venue-id in your UI?
or
2. how does one query the venue details using the twitter handle?

thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of a venue URL that contains only the twitter handle and not a venue id?

Answer (score 1):

Foursquare's [/users/search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/search) should work (you're basically searching for a "venue user"). https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=users/search%3Ftwitter%3Dwinkellyauto